# Automated Re-Naming of PDF Files in A folder in Windows based on their content

Tags: pdf, content-management-system

Good evening everyone,
i have a huge folder of scientific articles which have a cryptic file name. The journals are different, which means, that the systematic read of a pdf and extraction of content might be difficult. I want the PDFs renamed as following:

More than 3 authors:

Last Name Author 1 etal Year Title the first 10 words

2 Authors

Last Name Author 1 and Last Name Author 1 Year Title the first 10 words

Thank you so much for your help and have a nice weekend!
Cheers, Chris

I tried to read the pdfs in R and counted by letter the position of the informations but that cannot be the way to go since each journal has another format